# in R is there a better way for loops a dataframe to create 3d binary vector

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, vectorization

I have a dataframe that has a value that is a character and i need to convert the values to a 3d binary vector based on the value

```
 DF = data.frame(Names = c("A1","A2","A3","A4"), TestScore = c("100 pts","NA","45 pt","75 pt."))
```

I need to create a function to split the TestScore to just the numeric value that would contain only  the value (100,NA,50,75) and then create a 3d binary vector with of three categories where the 2nd and 3rd categories would be average vs best student. All 0 or NA would be consider the first category of NoScore. I need to use this 3d vector for analyzing the NoScore relationship to another variable

The only way I can think about it is do a for-loop on the rows of the dataframe, split the TestScore and then do an if-then else but I am not creating a 3d dimensional vector but I am creating 2 variable (Ind and Cat) that have values for Score but I think I should use my array of [i,j,k] to store values of 0 or 1.

Here is what I have for looking at the dataframe :

```
 my_awards_array <- array(0, dim=c(movie_nrow,3,3))

convert_Awards <- function(df){
    library(stringr)       
    awards_split_df = data.frame(str_split_fixed(df$TestScore," ",2))
    summary(awards_split_df)
    ls.str(awards_split_df)
    awards_split_df[] <- data.frame(lapply(awards_split_df,as.character),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    summary(awards_split_df)
    ls.str(awards_split_df)

    ############################################################################
    ## First column contain the Number to convert as the value for binary Vector
    ############################################################################


    ### Second column would be eliminated ("win" or "wins." "win.")
    awards_split_df$X2 <- NA
    awards_conv_df <- data.frame(lapply(awards_split_df,as.integer))
    colnames(awards_conv_df) = c("AwardsNum","AwardsType")
    awards_final_df <- awards_conv_df

    for (i in 1:nrow(awards_final_df)) {
            origAwardsNum = awards_final_df[i,c('AwardsNum')]
        if (is.na(origAwardsNum) ) {
                awards_final_df[i,c('AwardsCat')] = "NoAwards";
                awards_final_df[i,c('AwardsInd')] = 0;
                break
            } else if (origAwardsNum == 0 ){
                          awards_final_df[i,c('AwardsCat')] = "NoAwards";
                          awards_final_df[i,c('AwardsInd')] = 1;       
                          break
            } else if ((origAwardsNum) > 0 & (origAwardsNum <= 50)) {
                         awards_final_df[i,c('AwardsInd')] = 2;        
                         awards_final_df[i,c('AwardsCat')] = "SomeAwards";
                         break
            } else {
                         awards_final_df[i,c('AwardsInd')] = 3;        
                         awards_final_df[i,c('AwardsCat')] = "ManyAwards";
                         break
            }    

    }

    return(awards_final_df)
```

}

Here is the expected INPUT results

DF

```
    Names TestScore
  1    A1   100 pts
  2    A2        NA
  3    A3     45 pt
  4    A4    75 pt.
```

AFTER

```
    Names TestScore   AwardsCat     AwardsInd <- 3d binary vector [0,0,0]
  1    A1   100 pts   ManyAwards    [0,0,1]
  2    A2        NA   NA            NA
  3    A3     45 pt   SomeAwards    [0,1,0]
  4    A4    75 pt.   ManyAwards    [0,0,1]
```

UPDATE:

I have to improve my strsplit approach, I found out that the data for TestScore can come like this 
        TestScore = 45 pt & 10 bonus  --> which will equal to 45 + 10 = 55 to determine AwardsCat

Comment: The relationship between your example data frame `DF` and the `convert_Awards()` function is unclear. The function does not appear to use the column names present in `DF`, and you do not provide an example of the expected result.

Comment: @jdobres added more information ..